# Javascript substring not working as expected with long string

Tags: javascript

I have a VERY long string containing code from a Rich Text Editor. I need to split this up into 4 parts to save it to the database. I am doing this.

```
var fullPart = $('#summernote').summernote('code').replace("'", "\'");
var markupStr = fullPart.substring(0, 3000000);
var markupStr2 = fullPart.substring(3000000, 3000000);
var markupStr3 = fullPart.substring(6000000, 3000000);
var markupStr4 = fullPart.substring(6000000);
```

markupStr, markupStr3 and markupStr4 all contain values, but markupStr2 is empty.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `The substring() method returns the part of the string between the start and end indexes`

Comment: Your start index and end index is the same, so markupStr2 is empty.

Comment: Ah so it's not a length... great thank you. Can you write that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var markupStr2 = fullPart.substring(3000000, 3000000);`

**Explanation** : Start and End index are same in this  that is why you are getting empty results.

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) for more information.

> `str.substring(indexStart[, indexEnd])`
>
> ***indexStart*** The index of the first character to include in the returned
>   substring.
>
> ***indexEnd*** Optional. The index of the first character to exclude from
>   the returned substring.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple mistake. `fullpart.substring(3000000,3000000)` would return a string of length of 3,000,000 - 3,000,000 characters (0 characters). The correct way to do this is:

```
var fullPart = $('#summernote').summernote('code').replace("'", "\'");
var markupStr = fullPart.substring(0, 3000000);
var markupStr2 = fullPart.substring(3000000, 6000000);
var markupStr3 = fullPart.substring(6000000, 9000000);
var markupStr4 = fullPart.substring(12000000);
```